# Animate a div if clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, positioning

So, I've been studying jQuery lately and I saw some tutorials and it appears to be it doesn't work. So here what I wan to do..

Whenever I clicked #search_top, I want my #container css attribute, top, to be 60px else 0px.

Below is what I use.

```
$("#search_top").click(function() {
    if($("#container").top() == 60) {
        $("#container").animate({top:"0px"}, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#container").animate({top:"60px"}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance. :) Hope this question is very clear to you.

Comment: Do you use `absolute` or at least `relative` positioning?

Comment: On my container. I use absolute position

Comment: Does `.top()` exist? Try `.position().top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `.top()` does not exist. You can use `.offset().top` instead.

[jquery offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [jquery position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

> offset() - Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the document.
>
> position() - Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the offset parent.

```
$("#search_top").click(function() {
    if($("#container").offset().top == 60) {
        $("#container").animate({top:"0px"}, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#container").animate({top:"60px"}, 1000);
    }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dXDVh/4/)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should use

```
 if (parseInt($("#container").css('top')) == 60){
   //do stuff
 }
```

jQuery `.css()` method can be used to set or retrieve css properties. For more information, click [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)